# wget a zip file from GitHub, OpenSSL error

Tags: wget, openssl, error-handling, https

```
$ wget -O sindresorhus-is-online-master.zip https://github.com/sindresorhus/is-online/archive/master.zip
--2018-11-03 13:48:20--  https://github.com/sindresorhus/is-online/archive/master.zip
Resolving github.com... <ip>, <ip>
Connecting to github.com|<ip>|:443... connected.
OpenSSL: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

Wondering what to do to get wget working in this situation. I know how to download it fine with curl, or from the browser, but I'd like to know how to do it with wget in this situation.

Comment: It isn't issue in wget, it is issue in missing ssl libraries, for ssl to work.

Comment: Would like to know what to do to get it to work.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: I am using a Mac.

Comment: Did you try the `--secure-protocol=TLSv1` option?

Comment: Yes I tried that.

Comment: Specifying TLSv1 (1.0) won't help; since early this year **github requires TLS 1.2**, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48938385/ and links there. If your software supports 1.2 it should have used it automatically, so you probably need newer software. Or download to another machine and then transfer.

Comment: It seems to me that you're using either an old version of Wget which was compiled without TLSv1.2 support or your Wget links to an ancient SSL library. Sharing the output of your `wget --version` will help identify which case it is.

Comment: `$ wget --version` => `GNU Wget 1.14 built on darwin13.0.2.`. btw not sure what version >= of openssl i should have.