# Can not download from an HTTPS site (ssl) with wget?

Tags: debian, wget, ssl, error-handling

I know my version of wget is very old, but I can't get a download to work with it,

```
# wget https://github.com/radare/radare2/archive/master.zip
--2018-11-05 00:07:51--  https://github.com/radare/radare2/archive/master.zip
Resolving github.com... 192.30.253.112, 192.30.253.113
Connecting to github.com|192.30.253.112|:443... connected.
OpenSSL: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
Unable to establish SSL connection.

# wget --secure-protocol SSLv3 https://github.com/radare/radare2/archive/master.zip
--2018-11-04 23:06:12--  https://github.com/radare/radare2/archive/master.zip
Resolving github.com... 192.30.253.112, 192.30.253.113
Connecting to github.com|192.30.253.112|:443... connected.
OpenSSL: error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure
Unable to establish SSL connection.

# wget --secure-protocol SSLv2 https://github.com/radare/radare2/archive/master.zip
--2018-11-04 23:06:14--  https://github.com/radare/radare2/archive/master.zip
Resolving github.com... 192.30.253.113, 192.30.253.112
Connecting to github.com|192.30.253.113|:443... connected.
Unable to establish SSL connection.

# wget --secure-protocol TLSv1 https://github.com/radare/radare2/archive/master.zip
--2018-11-04 23:06:22--  https://github.com/radare/radare2/archive/master.zip
Resolving github.com... 192.30.253.112, 192.30.253.113
Connecting to github.com|192.30.253.112|:443... connected.
OpenSSL: error:1409442E:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:tlsv1 alert protocol version
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

I've tried adding `--no-check-certificate` but still no dice. Is there anyway to get grab an a `.zip` with an ancient version of `wget` on an `https` server?

In this case, it's a public tarball. And, I'm working on an iso made to test vulnerabilities (Protostar).

---

Using Wget 1.12 and OpenSSL 0.9.8 from [Debian Squeeze 6.0.3](https://www.debian.org/News/2011/20111008)

Comment: GitHub [appears to support TLS 1.2 only](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=github.com&s=192.30.255.112&hideResults=on), so the answer's probably to build your own copy of something.

Comment: @Vlastimil from the question "And, I'm working on an iso made to test vulnerabilities (Protostar)."

Comment: Dupe from just yesterday https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/479650/wget-a-zip-file-from-github-openssl-error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [wget a zip file from GitHub, OpenSSL error](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/479650/wget-a-zip-file-from-github-openssl-error)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Using Wget 1.12 and OpenSSL 0.9.8 from Debian Squeeze 6.0.3

OpenSSL 0.9.8 supports only TLS 1.0 and lower protocol versions (i.e. SSL 3.0). According to [ssllabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=github.com&s=192.30.255.112&latest), github.com supports only TLS 1.2.

Since there is no way to connect with a TLS 1.0 client to a site which is not willing to support TLS 1.0 the connection fails:

> tlsv1 alert protocol version

To get the file from GitHub you need to a TLS 1.2 capable client, like current browsers or a wget which is not linked against OpenSSL 0.9.8 but against an OpenSSL which at least version 1.0.1. You get these newer versions for example by upgrading to a newer Debian version - note that Debian 6 reached end of life in 2016 and your 6.0.3 has been unsupported for even longer.